# Laravel 5.5 file download Call to undefined method BinaryFileResponse::withCookie()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-response

After upgrading to Laravel 5.5, this code:

```
    $headers = ['Content-Type: ' . $fileData[2]];
    return Response::download($fileData[0], $fileData[1] ,$headers);
```

generates this error:

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::withCookie()

in CreateFreshApiToken.php (line 51)
at CreateFreshApiToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 149)
```

Any idea? Might it be a bug? It worked well with Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify what `CreateFreshApiToken.php` does. `Response::download` is returning `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse` and this class doesn't have `withCookie` method. In Laravel 5.4 it seems it was exactly the same. If it won't help include this class code and what middleware are you using in `App\Http\Kernel.php` file.

It seems something was broken in Laravel Passport in this PR http://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/474 . You can also look at http://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/489 and maybe remove this route from web middleware if it's possible as a temporary fix and wait for making fix in Laravel Passport

Comment: CreateFreshApiToken.php comes from Passport: 
vendor\laravel\passport\src\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken.php.  There is this line, before withCookie is called: 
if($this->shouldReceiveFreshToken($request, $response))

Comment: @PeterMatisko Are yo using latest Passport release (4.0.2) ?

Comment: @PeterMatisko It seems something was broken in https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/474 . You can also look at https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/489 and maybe remove this route from `web` middleware if it's possible as a temporary fix

Comment: I am doing some reverse engineering in the passport functions. Seems like "cookies" in $response is empty.